# How to solve this kind of Lagrangian function?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, summation, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose $\mathbf{a} = (a_{0}, \dots, a_{N-1})$ and $\mathbf{b} = (b_{0}, \dots, b_{N-1})$ with $a_{i}\geq0$, $b_{i}\geq 0$. I would like to minimize

$$-\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}a_{i}b_{i}$$

subject to

$$\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}b_{i} = 1.$$ The Lagrangian function is

$$L(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}, \lambda) = -\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}a_{i}b_{i} + \lambda\Bigg(\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}b_{i} -1\Bigg).$$ I assume I should be looking next the necessary conditions

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = 0,$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial a_{i}} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial b_{i}} = 0$$

for every $i$ but I don't know how to actually proceed from here. I will get a big system of equations with large $N$.

What I am trying to do is that I have a set of related real-world measurements $a_{i}$. I would like to find weights $b_{i}$ that maximize the sum of products $a_{i}b_{i}$. The sum of $b_{i}$ must be one, to avoid the thing going to infinity ($a$ is fixed in the beginning).

Intuitively, I think setting $b_{i} = 1/N$ for each $i$ gets me somewhere (mean) but not necessarily at the optimal point.

Comment: Hang on, are you varying the $a_i$ as well as the $b_i$? if so, the constraint on $b_i$ basically does nothing, and the minimum can be made $-\infty$.

Comment: @chappers I added an explanation of what I am trying to accomplish. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Is there any restriction on $a_i$ other than being positive? Oh, I see the edits; the $a_i$ are fixed, right?

Comment: @robjohn Yes, each $a_{i}$ is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lagrangian tells you that there is no interior critical point unless all the $a_i$ are equal. Thus, in general, the minimum will be on the boundary. In fact, it is in a corner.

Without loss of generality, let $a_0=\max\limits_{0\le i\le N-1}a_i$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
-\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}a_ib_i
&=-a_0\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}b_i+\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}(a_0-a_i)b_i\\
&\ge-a_0\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}b_i\\[6pt]
&=-a_0
\end{align}
$$
and you can get the sum to be $-a_0$ by setting $b_0=1$ and $b_i=0$ for $i\gt0$.

Thus, you want to put all the weight on the largest $a_i$.